# Path-connected and topology

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Hi everyone. I am a little bit confused about question 12.2 and 12.3.

I think, is it enough to say in question 12.3 that if we remove one point from $X \times Y$ then $X \times Y$ will still be path-connected, but if we remove a point from R then R is not path-connected.
Is it enough for answering question 12.3 or should there be more?

Then about question 12.2 I dont know really how to do?

Comment: For 12.2 argue exactly as if you were in a square minus the center: To connect $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$, first follow $(\gamma(t),b)$ from $(a,b)$ to $(c,b)$ using a path $\gamma$ that connects $a$ to $c$ in $X$. Then follow $(c,\delta(t))$ from $(c,b)$ to $(c,d)$.  The only thing that can prevent this is if $b=y$ and $\gamma$ passes through $x$. Then use $\delta$ and $\gamma$ in the reverse order. For 12.3 that is the argument, yes.

Comment: For 12.2, a path from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ could be along $(a,b)\to (a,d)\to (c,d)$ or along $(a,b)\to (c,b)\to (c,d)$. At least one allows you to avoid $(x,y)$.

Comment: Hi user517969 - I am a little bit confused about how I should choose γ(t) and δ(t)?

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: If $f:A\to B$ is a homeomorphism and $a\in A$ then $P^B_{f(a)}=f(P^A_a). $ So with $A=\Bbb R$ and $B=X\times Y,$  your approach to 12.3 is correct, by applying 12.2, as in the A by Andres Mejia.

Answer (score 1):

Since $2$ is answered in the comments, I'll just assume that it is proven.

Suppose that $\mathbb R \cong A \times B=X$. Clearly $A  \times B$ is path connected, and in particular, so are $A,B$ since projections onto each factor $\pi_1(X)=A$ and $\pi_2(X)=B$ are both continuous, we deduce that $A,B$ are path connected.

Remove some point $(p,q)$ from $X$, and by $12.2$, this is still path connected, but then the image of projections are $\mathbb R\setminus \{p\}$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \{q\}$  are disconnected, a contradiction.

Note that in the last part, the first assumption of $12.3$ is essential.